# How to export the full skype chat history of skype 8 on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, skype, history, export

I would like to export and view my complete skype chat history without using skype somehow.
I tried skype's online chat history exporter (https://secure.skype.com/en/data-export) in combination with the skype parser ( https://go.skype.com/skype-parser) to view the .json file.

However this combination only allows me to view conversations dating back to 11/15/2017 for a particular conversation while the skype application shows me the full history dating back to 04/24/2017.

Is there any possibility to make the missing part of the conversation exportable somehow ? I'm assuming the missing part might be locally stored on my computer and is not synced to the cloud.

I'm using windows 10 and skype 8.
Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/suurjaak/Skyperious

This software both explains the 2017 as well as helps you with your issue hopefully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1120397)